# Undefined index, isset and references in PHP

Tags: php, reference, isset

If accessing an undefined index of a null reference, PHP does not throw any errors.

```
<?php

$array = &$foo['bar'];
if ($array['stuff']) echo 'Cool'; // No PHP notice
$array['thing'] = 1; // Array created; $foo['bar']['thing'] == 1
$array['stuff']; // PHP notice
```

If `$array` wasn't a reference PHP would have complained on the first line.

Why doesn't it for references? Do I need bother with isset for null references, or is PHP complaining internally and not letting me know?

Comment: You reference is not to an array, so I don't think what you are asking makes sense.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but passing by reference is for functions or loops correct?

Comment: @Juan - You're right, undefined index wouldn't make sense. I would expect some E_NOTICE though. Undefined variable maybe? While `$array` may be set to something akin to `NULL` on line 1, once the array is created it still remembers the depth of the array as defined by line 1, which is.. interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `$array` is null. The following code will not give you a notice either:

```
$b = null;
if ($b['stuff']) echo 'cool';
```

This is strange, [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#103743) in the documentation points to that fact.

Answer (score 1):

You must raise your error reporting level. Your example `$array['stuff']` will throw warnings about index not found. I often combine a test for key in with the evaluation so as to prevent those warnings:

```
if( array_key_exists("blah",$arr) && strlen($arr['blah']) > 0 ) { 
    ; // do stuff here
}
```

I often combine variables in with array names because anytime I have to cut-n-paste copy code to the next section to do the same-ish thing, I'd rather make an array of variable names and then iterate through the variable names. The most absurd condition is when I have billing and shipping data to manipulate, where I'll have an array variable name `$BorS` or just `$BS` and then at the top, set `$BorS="shipping";` and end up with really interesting statements like:

```
${$BorS."data"}[${$BorS."_addr1"}]=$input_array[$BorS."_address_line_1"];
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just do:

```
$array = array();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything, I'm just curious about the behaviour.

Comment: it's because your error reporting is set a little to high. In a production environment you would disable php errors.

Comment: This answer did not address the question, it assumed the OP didn't know what they were talking about by showing a different way to do something. But the question is specifically about why does PHP not issue a warning.